# Create a custom NSAttributedString.Key Everything is normal, but it just doesn't show up and has no effect

Tags: swiftui, uikit, nsattributedstring

This question has been rummaged throughout the network. I customized a sizeFont sizeFont inherits UIFont. Can use func systemFont print is also normal and has been set. 
But the display has no effect.

My Configuration:

```
mac OS 11.1
iPhone 14.3
Xcode 12.3
```

I have tried the following methods.

1.
[Create custom NSAttributedString.Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62959316/create-custom-nsattributedstring-key)
But no effect

2.Simulator and real machine (No, no effect)

**this is my code**

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        UIkitTextView()
            .padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

extension NSAttributedString.Key {
    static let textStyle: NSAttributedString.Key = .init("textStyle")
}

struct UIkitTextView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    var fullString: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Hello, World")
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {
        let view = UITextView()
        
        let attributedtest: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
            .sizefont: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 72),
            .foregroundColor: UIColor.red,
        ]
        
        fullString.setAttributes(attributedtest, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: 5))
        
        view.attributedText = fullString
        print("\(fullString.attributedSubstring(from: NSRange(location: 0, length: 5)))")
        return view
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: Context) {
        
    }
}
class sizeFont: UIFont{
}
extension NSAttributedString.Key {
    static let sizefont: NSAttributedString.Key = .init(rawValue:"sizeFont")
}
```

And Picture

[image]

Thanks

Comment: You added a custom `NSAttributedString.Key`, BUT WHAT CODE will interpret it? It's inside CoreText that you read the attributes and render them. Apple won't read the yours when rendering. It's like adding "a screw" into an “furniture to build yourself", and expect the user the know that he/she has to use it, where and when.

Comment: Internally, you can check for instance https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslayoutmanager the Drawing methods, Apple will read for each necessary range the key, and call the correct method with the associated value. It's not: I read the value, get its type and guess what's the effect to apply. For instance, there are Keys which have the same kind of values (Int like underline, striking, etc.), how should it guess that's the value for striking or for underlining?

Answer (score 0):

My only experience with NSAttributed text is for smooth conversion of a integer to a smoothly scaled image.
This is how I did it, perhaps it can help :

```
func imageOf(_ val: Int, backgroundColor: UIColor = .gray, foregroundColor: UIColor = .yellow) -> UIImage {
    let t:String = (val==0) ? " " : String(val)
    let attributes = [
        NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: foregroundColor,
        NSAttributedString.Key.backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
        NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 70)
    ]
    let textSize = t.size(withAttributes: attributes)
    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: textSize)
    let newImage = renderer.image(actions: { _ in t.draw(at: CGPoint(x: 0, y:0), withAttributes: attributes) })
    return newImage
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ask you this:
How iOS is supposed to know what effect to apply according to your new `NSAttributedString.Key`? How to render it?
By reading the only value (and not the key) and act according its type? If so, how could iOS know that an UIColor value is for `NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor` or for `NSAttributedString.Key.backgroundColor`.

In other words, you added information, but noone reads your mind and knows what to do with that.

You'd have to play with [`CoreText.framework`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretext), with useful infos [there](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/CustomTextProcessing/CustomTextProcessing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH4).

As seen, you can play more with a [`NSLayoutManager`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslayoutmanager). For instance, at stome point [`drawUnderline(forGlyphRange:underlineType:baselineOffset:lineFragmentRect:lineFragmentGlyphRange:containerOrigin:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslayoutmanager/1403079-drawunderline) will be called, and will render it.
Are you starting to see the logic, who will call that method with which params? Applied to your new key/value, which code will call the corresponding method?

I guess it should be in the `NSAttributedString.Key.font`, so you might have a method to convert it into the correct key. Maybe it's for a toggle (toggle between currently set font, and the value of `sizeFont`?), But according to the name, why not just put a `CGFloat` value?

You might ask a new question explaining what's the effect you want. But this answer should answer "why it's not working", or rather, "why it's not doing anything" (because working, I don't know what's supposed to do in the first place).